My Renault Clio IV 2017 not reading the card key
The battery is light is not coming on, on the dashboard, and not starting, no power on the car, only lights come on?

Powdery bluish white deposits on battery terminals? Can both cable terminals twist easily? A warm water and baking soda mixture using an old tooth brush will dissolve and neutralize dried battery acid, water rinse. Tighten connections and check battery negative connections to chassis and engine block. A boost from another car battery may get you started, then visit any auto store for free battery/alternator testing on the car.

Can write this sentence more clearly, I can't understand it properly?: "The battery is light is not coming on the dashboard and not starting no power on the car only lights come"
